# PHP - Parse ini file and access single values

Tags: php, python, ini

In Python you can parse an `.ini` file and access the single values like this:

**myini.ini**

```
[STRINGS]
mystring = fooooo
value = foo_bar
```

**script.py**

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

config.read("myini.ini")

test = config["STRINGS"]["mystring"]
print (test)      #-> OUTPUT: fooooo
```

How can I do the same in PHP? Unfortunately, I was not able to find any examples.

Comment: Does [this function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) work for you?

Comment: I already read that page, but i still can't figure out how to do it. Maybe someone can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not to fear, parsing an `.ini` file is a standard method. (See [parse_ini_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) in the php docs).

Using your file as the base of this example:

**myini.ini**

```
[STRINGS]
mystring = fooooo
value = foo_bar
```

**test.php**

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("myini.ini");
print_r($ini_array); # prints the entire parsed .ini file

print($ini_array['mystring']); #prints "fooooo"
```

Note that by default `parse_ini_file` ignores sections and gloms all ini settings into the same object. If you'd like to have things scoped sectionally as in your python example, pass `true` for the `process_sections` parameter (second parameter).

**test2.php**

```
$ini_array = parse_ini_file("myini.ini", true /* will scope sectionally */);

print($ini_array['mystring']); #prints nothing
print($ini_array['STRINGS']['mystring']); #prints fooooo
```

Comment: This does not help me because it prints all values, i only want to store a single value (mystring) into a variable.

Comment: Updated to demonstrate!

Comment: Also, I added an example of how to process ini files by sections since PHP does not do that by default.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why this is not included in the official documentation? Perhaps i missed it.

Comment: Scroll down to the Parameters section: http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

Comment: There is no example or info about how to do it, where do you mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100786/discussion-between-mjk-and-edwardblack).

Comment: Is everything this complex and ambiguous in PHP?

Comment: Probably. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: If there are uncoded `=` equal signs in the parameter value (as there may be in Windows .url shortcut files), parse_ini_file() will return false. Fixed by passing `INI_SCANNER_RAW` as the third parameter.

Answer (score 0):

From the intermediate approach, to get match section, it needs to read any INI file from line to line, in this case you can use fgets function or stream_get_line function to read for each line until the section founded or end of file (not founded).

Inside every line we can use preg_match (using regex pattern) that match with the actual section name been searched.

The essential of this approach is to reduce memory usage meanwhile many concurrent request occurs at the same time,  so in this case we use string object with any sufficient length as a buffer.

Good luck Buddy.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to read a single value from php.ini into a variable is with the ini_get() function like this:

```
$php_ini_option_name = 'error_reporting';
$php_ini_option_value = ini_get($php_ini_option_name);
echo "PHP.ini option '" . $php_ini_option_name . "' = " . $php_ini_option_value;
```

This will return the string value of the configuration option on success. According to the docs it will print an empty string for NULL values, or FALSE if the option doesn't exist in php.ini but that doesn't match my experience. From memory if the value is set as 'On' in php.ini ini_get will return '1'. This would lead one to expect that a value set to 'Off' would return '0' but it usually returned a blank string for me. Also, non existent option names usually return a blank string. I don't remember dealing with NULL so your mileage may vary on that. Basically you need to be aware of and prepared to handle what your system returns for special cases.

ini_get should be available in all versions of PHP >= 4.