# PHP include array-content from file

Tags: php, arrays, include

I am trying to optimize log-performance.

Till now I am using Fileappend() to create the log & file() + foreach line + explode() to show it.

What I want to get:

```
<?php
    $tmp = [
    include("log.php")
    ];

    print_r($tmp); 
?>
```

log.php:

```
"test"=>"haus",
"test2"=>"haus2",
```

This would make thinks faster & easier. Any idea?

Comment: If you can change the log file format to an *ini* file format, you could use the code in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814054/php-parse-ini-file-and-access-single-values. This does assume unique values for the key though.

Comment: I think parsing an ini is as bad on performance as my old solution

Comment: I don't know - I can't compare the two.  But I would expect the ini file parsing to be faster - by how much I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it could be done this way:

log.php:

```
<?php

return [
    "test"=>"haus",
    "test2"=>"haus2",
];
```

And in your file:

```
<?php

$tmp = include("log.php");

print_r($tmp);
```

Comment: Yes, but i would like to use Fileappend for the log. I can't rewrite the whole log every time to the disk.